# Co-trees of a simple graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matrices

Consider fundamental cycles (say $k$ of them) of a specific spanning tree of a simple graph (with $m$ edges) which is also connected and has no one-edge bonds.

Make the graph directed (in an arbitrary way) and each cycle directed (to follow consistently one of the two possible orientations); then create a matrix **C** with $k$ rows and $m$ columns whose elements indicate whether an edge is a part of the cycle (by $1$ or $-1$ when the two orientations agree or not, respectively) or not (by 0).

How would one prove the following:

Selecting $k$ columns of the matrix, the corresponding sub-determinant equals to $1$ or $-1$ when the corresponding edges contain no bond, equals to 0 otherwise.

A bit more challenging would be to prove that **C** is totally unimodular.

(My original contention that there was a unique bijection between edges of a cotree and fundamental cycles a potentially different spanning tree has been disproved below).

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponds"?

Comment: What should be unique?

Comment: I am sorry, the previous (and accepted) answer was wrong in one direction. Actually the claim simply does not hold: if the bijection exists, it may be not a cotree.

Comment: well, i see. Then it remains to do two things: prove the uniqueness when $S$ is a cotree; prove that $S$ is a cotree when the bijections exists and is unique.

Comment: hm, it looks that it is not always unique, please check my example

Comment: You are right, unique implies cotree but not reverse. All I want to prove is that the C matrix is totally unimodular - perhaps there is some more direct, matrix-algebra way?

Comment: I added the proof of total unimodularity

Comment: How do you relate vectors of edge space to vectors of vertex space - could you elaborate on 'embedding to the hyperplane'

Comment: Edge $e$ which goes from $u$ to $v$ correspinds to $v-u$. This extends to an isomorphism between the span of edges of a tree and the hyperplane "sum of coordinates equals 0" in the span of vertices.

Comment: So, the $f_j$ edges could could be parallel or loop edges of the new tree (unlike in the original *simple* graph), is this correct?

Comment: yes, such things may appear after contraction. But I do not think that being simple was crucial.

Comment: I still don't see how using vertex space makes it clear; suppose this is the graph: $e_1 = 1 \rightarrow2, e_2 = 2\rightarrow4, e_3 = 3\rightarrow2, f_1 = 2\rightarrow1, f_2 = 4\rightarrow2, f_3 = 4\rightarrow3$, the corresponding **C** would then be simply [[100],[010],[011]], while the vertex-space representation of the edges is $e_1=[1,-1,0,0], e_2=[0,1,0,-1], e_3=[0,-1,1,0], f_1=[-1,1,0,0], f_2=[0,-1,0,1], f_3=[0,0,-1,1]$ - I still cannot see the clear connection and simplification.

Comment: wait,  the corresponding **C** should be $3\times 6$. Also what is $r$? We use introduce the vertex representation only after contraction.

Comment: I think I understand the dependent part of the argument now, but still struggling with 'independent over any field' - would not that require some sort of contradiction argument?

Comment: if there is no cycle (after contraction), these $f$'s form a forest, and you may prove independence by induction starting with $f_i$ which is incident to a leaf.

Comment: This opens an interesting question: In a (simple) graph with n vertices and 2(n-1) edges, how many of its spanning trees (whose number can be easily established), have cotrees without cycles.

Comment: it depends on the graph, as well as the number of spanning trees

Comment: # of spanning trees equals to $det(C.C^t)$ - any such formula for # of acyclic cotrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix a spanning tree $T\subset E$ in a connected graph $G=(V,E)$. It defines fundamental cycles $C_1,\ldots,C_k$, $k=|E|-|T|$: for any $e\in E\setminus T$ take the unique cycle in $T\cup \{e\}$.

Let first $k$ columns of **C** correspond to the edges in $E\setminus T$. Then the first $k$ columns form a matrix with $\pm 1$ on the diagonal and zeros outside the diagonal. Consider an $r\times r$ minor of **C**, we should prove that it either 0 or $\pm 1$. By the structure of the first $k$ columns, this reduces to the case when all $r$ columns of the minor correspond to $r$ edges $e_1,\ldots,e_r$ of a tree, let $r$ its rows correspond to $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ of $E\setminus T$. We contract all edges of $T$ except $e_1,\ldots,e_r$. I claim that if the set $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ does not contain a cycle, the corresponding rows are linearly independent over any field (thus the minor is $\pm 1$), and if they do contain a cycle, the rows are dependent with the coefficients $\pm 1$ (thus the minor is 0). For seeing this, we embed the span of the edges $e_1,\ldots,e_r$ to the hyperplane in the vertex space of the (new) tree $\tilde{T}$: each edge $e_i=uv$ corresponds to the vector $v-u$. With this embedding, the row which correspond to edge $f_j=uv$ corresponds to $\pm(v-u)$. The above claim is now clear.

Below is a couple of claims concerning the previous version of the question.

We have the following

**Theorem 1.** If set $S\subset E$ is a cotree (a complement of a spanning tree), then there exists a bijection $f\colon S\to \{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that $e\in C_{f(e)}$ for all $e\in S$.

**Proof.**
To prove that such a bijection exists, by Hall lemma (for the natural bipartite graph with parts $S$ and $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ corresponding to a relation $(e,i):e\in C_i$) it suffices to prove that the union $C_0$ of any $m=1,2,\ldots,k$ fundamental cycles contain at least $m$ elements of $S$. Denote $T_0=T\cap C_0$. Then $T_0$ is a forest, and it is an inclusion-maximal subforest of $C_0$ (since after adding to $T_0 $any edge in $C_0\setminus T$ you get a fundamental cycle). Assume that on the contrary $|S\cap C_0|\leqslant m-1$, this is equivalent to $|(E\setminus S)\cap C_0|\geqslant |C_0|-m+1=r+1$. But $E\setminus S$ is a tree, then $(E\setminus S)\cap C_0$ is a subforest of $C_0$, and it has more edges than an inclusion-maximal subforest $T_0$ of $C_0$. A contradiction.

The converse does not hold. For example, consider the graph[image: on the picture] (the black edges constitute a spanning tree, take the edge $e_1$ in the fundamental cycle $C_1$ and $e_2$ in $C_2$. The set $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is not a cotree, however.)

Also, the bijection is not always unique.[image: Here]
(the spanning tree is black) three edges $e_1,e_2,e_3$ may be paired with fundamental cycles by different ways.

Finally, I prove

**Theorem 2.** Assume that set $S\subset E$ is such that there exists *unique* bijection $f\colon S\to \{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that $e\in C_{f(e)}$ for all $e\in S$. Then $S$ is a cotree.

**Proof.** Consider the cut matroid of $G$: the bases are cotrees, the independent sets are subsets of cotrees. Let $e_1,\ldots,e_k$ be all elements of $E\setminus T$ enumerated so that $e_i\in C_i$. Note that $f\in C_i$ if and only if $(T\cup e_i)\setminus f$ is a tree, that is, $((E\setminus T)\setminus e_i)\cup f=f\cup \{e_j:j\ne i\}$ is a cotree. That is, if $f$ does not belong to a flat generated by $\{e_j:j\ne i\}$. Our matroid is a vector matroid, so this may be said as "the coefficient of $e_i$ in the expansion of $f$ in the basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ is non-zero". That is, we are given that the matrix of vectors of $S$ in the basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ has unique generalized diagonal with non-zero elements. This yields that the determinant of this matrix is non-zero, so, it is non-singular and $S$ constitutes a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 2 different spanning trees of the graph, and the corresponding cotrees and fundamental cycles. Then $$C_2=C_2|S_1*C_1$$ spells out the algebraic details of the following well-known fact: every fundamental cycle of Type 2 is a linear combination of fundamental cycles of Type 1 with coefficients from the ${0,1,-1}$ set; $C_2|S_1$ implies selecting only those columns/edges of $C_2$ which are in the first cotree (these are the coefficients of the linear combinations).

Now, selecting only columns which are in $S_2$ from each side of this equation yields $$C_2|S_2=C_2|S_1*C_1|S_2$$ Since the determinant of the LHS matrix is equal to either $1$ or $-1$ (there is exactly one way of matching each edge of a cotree with the corresponding fundamental cycle, only *one* of the $k!$ term of the determinant is non-zero). This implies that (integer-valued) determinants of each of the RHS matrices have the same property (being equal to $1$ or $-1$).

When the $k$ edges contain a bond, there is a linear combination of the corresponding columns of **C** (with coefficients from the $1,-1$ set) which yields a zero vector (a bond has to be traversed both ways by each cycle - the two contributions always cancel). This implies that these columns are linearly dependent and the corresponding determinant is thus equal to $0$.

The totally unimodular issue: It's known (and I take it for granted) that **C** is unimodular if and only if it's possible to find a linear combination of any selection of its rows such that (i) the coefficients are either $1$ or $-1$, (ii) the resulting elements are all from the $0,1,-1$ set.

To find such coefficients, one must first simply add the selected rows and apply 'mod 2' to each component of the answer (getting a vector of ones and zeros); this defines an undirected closed trail (revisiting vertices is allowed). Give this trail a consistent orientation (there may be several ways of doing it) by changing the sign of some of the $1$ components; the corresponding sign of the unique co-tree component of each row of **C** tells us whether the row should be added or subtracted - the answer will match the already constructed directed trail.